# PHPMailer is not working php-alt and in Directnic server, There is no error showing

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer for sending mails to custom input emails. It is working in hostgator server without any issues. After I migrate it to directnic server, it is not working. I don't know why there is no errors coming when I even add error_reporting. When we add $mail->send(), nothing is showing.

This server using php-alt function. Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is “php-alt function”? “Not working” isn’t helpful ever, there are errors, exceptions and return values which you should be able to inspect and report on. Lastly, have you gone through _all_ items [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/231316)

Comment: Most likely your new hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, which is covered extensively in the PHPMailer docs and hundreds of questions on here.